# How to bind SQL Server Time value to dropdown list in ASP.Net Web forms?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, webforms, formatting

I'm trying to figure out why this wont work.  Any help or insight would be appreciated.  I'm trying to bind to a Time column in the selected value for a drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lblReadyTime" runat="server"
    DataTextFormatString="{0:htt}"
    SelectedValue='<%#Bind("ReadyTime", "{0:htt}")%>'>
    <asp:ListItem Text="12AM" Value="12AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1AM" Value="1AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2AM" Value="2AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="3AM" Value="3AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="4AM" Value="4AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="5AM" Value="5AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="6AM" Value="6AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="7AM" Value="7AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="8AM" Value="8AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="9AM" Value="9AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="10AM" Value="10AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="11AM" Value="11AM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="12PM" Value="12PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1PM" Value="1PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2PM" Value="2PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="3PM" Value="3PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="4PM" Value="4PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="5PM" Value="5PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="6PM" Value="6PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="7PM" Value="7PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="8PM" Value="8PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="9PM" Value="9PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="10PM" Value="10PM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="11PM" Value="11PM" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to a `DateTime` first and then get the correct time.

```
SelectedValue='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("ReadyTime")).ToString("htt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>'
```

Comment: This gives me an error

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

Comment: Adding a .ToString() to Eval helped me get past that error, but then it tells me the value it is trying to bind to is not in the list. 'lblReadyTime' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Comment: What is the DataType of `ReadyTime`?

Comment: It seems to be coming through as a TimeSpan from a Time column.

Comment: So the column is a time column, not a datetime?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making the values match the Time literals I wanted and getting rid of the formatting references.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lblReadyTime" runat="server"
    SelectedValue='<%#Bind("ReadyTime")%>'>
    <asp:ListItem Text="12AM" Value="00:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1AM" Value="01:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2AM" Value="02:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="3AM" Value="03:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="4AM" Value="04:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="5AM" Value="05:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="6AM" Value="06:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="7AM" Value="07:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="8AM" Value="08:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="9AM" Value="09:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="10AM" Value="10:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="11AM" Value="11:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="12PM" Value="12:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1PM" Value="13:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2PM" Value="14:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="3PM" Value="15:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="4PM" Value="16:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="5PM" Value="17:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="6PM" Value="18:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="7PM" Value="19:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="8PM" Value="20:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="9PM" Value="21:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="10PM" Value="22:00:00" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="11PM" Value="23:00:00" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```